# Replace comma with an underscore calculated field SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to replace a comma from a single line of text field with an underscore(this I managed to do), but I want to replace it if a certain criteria is met - if the value in the field contains a comma to replace it with an underscore and if it doesn't, to leave the field with the value it already has. Here's the formula I managed to put together and only the part where it replaces the comma with an underscore works. If the field doesn't contain any commas though it just puts `#VALUE!` inside of the calculated field.

```
=IF((FIND(",",[TestField])),REPLACE([TestField],FIND(",",[TestField]),1,"_"),[TestField])
```

Comment: you could try using a SP2013 workflow to do this kind of action if that is an option.  There is a command to find a character in a substring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using below formula, this works for me:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(",",[TestField])),REPLACE([TestField],FIND(",",[TestField]),1,"_"),[TestField])
```

Comment: Have you tries this? Try this and let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome. Please upvote and accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, want to ask you how to edit the formula you gave me to work for more than 1 comma, let's say we have 1,023,012 ? For the moment it replaces the first comma, but doesn't replace the second. How can we have it replace all commas, no matter of the number?

Comment: Not sure if the number of commas are varying but if you know the number of commas you can create the formula as given [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/66e2ae2a-4da9-4c58-a8bb-cf46b1bf448f/calculated-column-to-replace-commas?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy). If the number of commas are not fixed then maybe you can do it using workflow or something.

Comment: Thank you Ganesh! If I want it for two commas then, would it be something like this, as I tried it and it didn't work:

Comment: =IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(",",[Finance Risk Trigger Value])),REPLACE([Finance Risk Trigger Value],FIND(",",[Finance Risk Trigger Value]),1,"|"),FIND(",",[Finance Risk Trigger Value]),1,"|"),[Finance Risk Trigger Value],(FIND(",",[Finance Risk Trigger Value])),REPLACE([Finance Risk Trigger Value],FIND(",",[Finance Risk Trigger Value]),1,"|"),FIND(",",[Finance Risk Trigger Value]),1,"|"),[Finance Risk Trigger Value])

Comment: there are so many syntax errors in this formula, can you please try the formula provided [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/66e2ae2a-4da9-4c58-a8bb-cf46b1bf448f/calculated-column-to-replace-commas?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy)? Or you can also create a new question with all details. someone else might help you with more efficient and easy formula.

Comment: In your case? will there always be two commas in your formula? or number of commas are not fixed? For fixed 2 commas you can use `=REPLACE(REPLACE([Finance Risk Trigger Value],SEARCH(",",[Finance Risk Trigger Value]),1,"|"),SEARCH(",",REPLACE([Finance Risk Trigger Value],SEARCH(",",[Finance Risk Trigger Value]),1,"|")),1,"|")`.

Comment: Thank you Ganesh!Commas won't be fixed.

Comment: Once it might be one, other time two.

Comment: Will open a new question for this, the REPLACE formula gives me the #VALUE!

Comment: Yes, I am trying to achieve the same. will update you.

Comment: Thank you. Opened a new question for that if you want to have the answer there:

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/266505/replace-more-than-one-comma-formula

Comment: Hi Ganesh, hope you are alright. Just to ask if you managed to make it work for two commas? I tried a few things myself, but didn't work so far. Even if it accepts the formula, it doesn't show the value in the actual field.