# Replace More Than One Comma Formula

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to replace more than one comma from a single line of text field with an underscore, or some other symbol, but I want to replace it if a certain criteria is met - if the value in the field contains a comma, or there'll be cases it'd contain two commas, to replace it with an underscore and if it doesn't, to leave the field with the value it already has. Here's the formula I have:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(",",[ColumnName])),REPLACE([ColumnName],FIND(",",[ColumnName]),1,"|"),FIND(",",[ColumnName]),1,"|"),[ColumnName])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a JavaScript solution, posting it here as well. Just replace the Column Name with the name of your column:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

    var fieldContext = {};
    fieldContext.Templates = {};
    fieldContext.Templates.Fields = {     
       "Column Name": { "View": fieldTemplate }
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(fieldContext);
});
function fieldTemplate(ctx) {
    var field = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
    return field.replace(/\,/g, '|');
}
</script>
```